# Get the URL for a resource in an OS X framework

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks

I want to get the url for a core data model that I have in an OS X framework. I've tried using [NSBundle mainBundle] urlForResource]... but the bundle it gets its from the running application not the framework.

So whats the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### solution

you need a Class (any) that is in the framework and then you can use that

```
Class frameworkClass = ... //(self.class or NSClassFromString or [myClass class])
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:frameworkClass];
NSURL *url = [frameworkBundle urlForResource:...];
```

#### example.

I often have a class that is in one of my frameworks:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@"jpg"];
```